# caching django querysets, debug toolbar shows queries still running on page load

Tags: python, django, caching, python-3.x, django-queryset

I've read through the docs several times and still am not getting what I need.  I believe I am caching and pickling a query set which should be evaluated by django so the query is not executed on page load, it uses cached results at the time of the cache object creation.  But the debug toolbar is showing that the queries are still running when the page loads.  So I'm assuming I'm just caching the query and not the results.  Below is my code, any help would be great, I've been stuck on this for a few days now. thanks.

management command to generate the cache key, value:

```
    images_query = ImageAssociations.objects.filter(place_id = place_id).order_by(-image_score')[:10]
    images = pickle.dumps(images_query)  
    cache.set('images', images, timeout=9999)
```

Views.py

```
    images_cache = cache.get('images')
    images = pickle.loads(images_cache)
    args = {}
    args['images'] = images
    return render_to_response('place.html', args)
```

Comment: Please show more code. Full view, place in template where you looping for images. And where do you call caching?

Comment: Are you sure that cache is set? Try to `cache.get('images')` right after `cache.set`. There is a chance that results of query can't be pickled or your cache can't handle that object because of size or whatever